# How to use .each of jquery in a for loop to highlight one label at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

```
$(this).click(function){
$('.text').each(function(){
$(this).css('color''#C4BD97')
});
});
```

This is my code using jquery to highlight a label of the series in flot graph  onclicking a corresponding plot on the graph. The problem I am facing is I click on the  point on the flot graph but only the last label in the yaxis is highlighted. I want to   highlight the label by clicking the point on the corresponding plot. But this code is  highlighting only the last label whichever plot is clicked. Even if plot is clicked on  different series the same last label is highlighted.

```
This function has a for loop where it takes each series to add the label to each  series. 
my function
function addLabels(axis,ticks) {
/*some statements
for(i=1;i<axis.length;++i)
{
  }
*/

addLabels(axes.yaxis,function(tick,axes){
return '<div class="text" style=position: absolute ; some calculation +ticklabel /div>'
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML ?

Comment: `$(this).click()`? is it in any handler?

Comment: @user2029107 If possible then please provide your code and HTML... :)

Answer (score 1):

I made 3 modifications to your code.

First, you had an extra `)` in your code, and your statement was missing a semicolon, and your `css()` was missing a comma.

Next, I removed the .each(), because it's implicit in the selector.

Finally, I assumed you wanted only the `.text` element from the element being clicked, and told it to only change the color of the `.text` which is subordinate to it.

```
$(this).click(function(){
   $(this).find('.text').css('color', '#C4BD97');
});
```

If my assumption supporting the third change was incorrect, then just use this:

```
$(this).click(function(){
   $('.text').css('color', '#C4BD97');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I would like to know if it works for each iteration of for. Because its highlighting only the last label ie the last iteration of for.

Comment: My first example will automatically select all CHILD elements of the clicked element with the `.text` class. My second example will select ALL elements with that class in the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery correctly:

```
$(this).click(function(){
$('.text').each(function(){
$(this).css('color':'#C4BD97');
});
});
```

Comment: Sir the HTML code is written in javascript itself. I have put up the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Doing $(this).click(function) can't work !

Just do `.click(function (){`

by the way, $(this).css('color''#C4BD97') can't work without "," ! -> `$(this).css('color','#C4BD97')`

Comment: if i just do .click(function(){ will it work? I have to highlight the corresponding label when the corresponding plot is clicked. 
And the css you have told is right i have used the same in my program .

Comment: If click event is bind it can be better. 
The fact is that atm you are doing this: when you click on something, every text class are going to change of color. Is it really what you want to do ?
Don't do $(this).click, put your click on a div or class

Comment: No sir i dont want all the text class to highlight. I want only the corresponding label to highlight. For instance in a flot graph i have 4 series plotted . Each has few nodes if that node is clicked the corresponding series label to be highlighted which is in  the same text class. I want to highlight one label at a time whivh is in the same class